# What is the most efficient way of moving data out of Hive and into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

Is there an elegant, easy and fast way to move data out of Hive into MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the export with the [Hadoop-MongoDB](http://api.mongodb.org/hadoop/MongoDB+Hadoop+Connector.html) connector. Just run the Hive query in your job's main method. This output will then be used by the Mapper in order to insert the data into `MongoDB`.

**Example:**

Here I'm inserting a semicolon separated text file (*id;firstname;lastname*) to a MongoDB
collection using a simple Hive query :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

import com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.io.BSONWritable;
import com.mongodb.hadoop.util.MongoConfigUtil;

public class HiveToMongo extends Configured implements Tool {

    private static class HiveToMongoMapper extends
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, BSONWritable> {

        //See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-634
        private static final String HIVE_EXPORT_DELIMETER = '\001' + "";
        private IntWritable k = new IntWritable();
        private BSONWritable v = null;

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) 
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String [] split = value.toString().split(HIVE_EXPORT_DELIMETER);

            k.set(Integer.parseInt(split[0]));
            v = new BSONWritable();
            v.put("firstname", split[1]);
            v.put("lastname", split[2]);
            context.write(k, v);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to load Hive Driver");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default");

            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();    
            String sql = "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY " +
                    "'hdfs://localhost:8020/user/hive/tmp' select * from users";
            stmt.executeQuery(sql);

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }

        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new HiveToMongo(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Path inputPath = new Path("/user/hive/tmp");
        String mongoDbPath = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:6900/mongo_users.mycoll";
        MongoConfigUtil.setOutputURI(conf, mongoDbPath);

        /*
        Add dependencies to distributed cache via 
        DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(...) :
        - mongo-hadoop-core-x.x.x.jar
        - mongo-java-driver-x.x.x.jar
        - hive-jdbc-x.x.x.jar
        HadoopUtils is an own utility class
        */
        HadoopUtils.addDependenciesToDistributedCache("/libs/mongodb", conf);
        HadoopUtils.addDependenciesToDistributedCache("/libs/hive", conf);

        Job job = new Job(conf, "HiveToMongo");

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, inputPath);
        job.setJarByClass(HiveToMongo.class);
        job.setMapperClass(HiveToMongoMapper.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(MongoOutputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

        job.submit();
        System.out.println("Job submitted.");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

One drawback is that a **'staging area'** (/user/hive/tmp) is needed to store the intermediate Hive output. Furthermore as far as I know the Mongo-Hadoop connector **doesn't support upserts.**

I'm not quite sure but you can also try to fetch the data from `Hive` without running
`hiveserver` which exposes a Thrift service so that you can probably save some overhead.
Look at the source code of Hive's `org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver#processLine(String line, boolean allowInterupting)` method which actually executes the query. Then you can hack together something like this:

```
...
LogUtils.initHiveLog4j();
CliSessionState ss = new CliSessionState(new HiveConf(SessionState.class));
ss.in = System.in;
ss.out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
ss.err = new PrintStream(System.err, true, "UTF-8");
SessionState.start(ss);

Driver qp = new Driver();
processLocalCmd("SELECT * from users", qp, ss); //taken from CliDriver
...
```

Side notes:

There's also a [hive-mongo](https://github.com/yc-huang/Hive-mongo) connector implementation you might also check.
It's also worth having a look at the implementation of the [Hive-HBase](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration) connector to get some idea if you want to implement a similar one for `MongoDB`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Sqoop](https://blogs.apache.org/sqoop/entry/apache_sqoop_overview)? It's supposed to make it very simple to move data between Hadoop and SQL/NoSQL databases. [This article](http://ankitasblogger.blogspot.com/2012/01/sqoop-export-and-import-commands.html) also gives an example of using it with Hive.

Comment: Sqoop only supports transfer between hadoop and relational database for the moment : http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_supported_databases

Comment: As @Jp Bond pointed out Sqoop can be used with JDBC-compliant DBs, but there's no JDBC support for MongoDB: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-539

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `hadoop-MongoDB` connector project :

http://api.mongodb.org/hadoop/MongoDB%2BHadoop+Connector.html

"This connectivity takes the form of allowing both reading MongoDB data into Hadoop (for use in MapReduce jobs as well as other components of the Hadoop ecosystem), as well as writing the results of Hadoop jobs out to MongoDB."

not sure if it will work for your use case but it's worth looking at.